# JSch How do I retrieve results from a series of piped commands

Tags: java, jsch

My COMMAND has a first part whose results are piped into a second part. When I run the code I always get returned the results of the first part, and the filter applied by the second part is apparently not executed.

So I get :

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE  COMMAND   CREATED      STATUS       PORTS   NAMES
abcdeff        a/b/1  "usr/.."  15 mins ago  Up to 2 mins         something.1.2
123abcd        a/b/2  "usr/.."  32 mins ago  exited               something.1.3
234456d        a/b/3  "usr/.."  2 days ago   exited               something.1.4
```

Where I want

```
CONTAINER
abcdeff
123abcd
234456d
```

```
public class Test {

  private static COMMAND =
  "echo \"password\" | sudo -S bash -c \"docker container ls --all | awk '{print $1}'\""

  executeExecCommand(command){
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session=jschgetSession(username, ipaddress, 22);
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    session.setConfif("PreferredAuthentications", "password");
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand(COMMAND);
    channel.setInputStream(null);
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
    InputStream input = channel.getInputStream();
    InputStream error = channel.getExtInputStream();
    channel.connect();
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> errorOutput = new ArrayList<>();

    try (InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(input);
      BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
      InputStreamReader errorReader = new InputStreamReader(error)) {

       String line = null;
       while (true) {
         while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine() != null {
         output.add(line:
         System.out.println("line = " + line);

       etc
       etc
       }
     }
}
```

Is this something to do with the piped process being executed in a different shell on the target server?
If so, how do I achieve my goal of returning the filtered list?

Comment: Doe you command work as you want, when you login to the `ipaddress` with a regular SSH terminal client?

Comment: Hello @Martin. Yes, I should have said that when I log into the server and run the piped command at the command line, it does work. I can apply several pipes and incrementally filter the results.

Comment: Hi @Martin  I put the piped command in a script called cleanup.sh in /home/abcd on the target server and run the command:"echo \"password\" | sudo -S bash -c \"/home/abcd/cleanup,sh\"";  This works.  But I'd rather not rely on a script existing on any remote server

Comment: Can you show us a simplest command that still has the same problem?

Comment: @Martin : that is the simplest command. (The full command has 3 pipes). This is simply retrieving a list of details of docker containers and printing out the 1st argument in each list

Comment: It seems it's the awk '{print $1}' which isn't getting executed. I can pipe to different grep -v filters successfully. Just the awk ' {print $1}' not working

Comment: Ha!!   I needed to escape the $.   COMMAND =
  "echo \"password\" | sudo -S bash -c \"docker container ls --all | awk '{print \\$1}'\"" works

Comment: So in other words, it was not the simplest command that still has the problem. And the problem has nothing to do with the pipes. And the command, as is, won't work in a normal shell session, despite you claiming otherwise => Hence this is not Java question.

Comment: @Martin.  Yes. That's the way it turned out.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to escape the $. COMMAND = "echo \"password\" | sudo -S bash -c \"docker container ls --all | awk '{print \$1}'\"" works

Note that if I want to further develop this command to delete containers for instance, I also need to escape the backtick.

COMMAND = "echo \"password\" | sudo -S bash -c \"docker container rm `docker container ls --all | awk '{print \$1}'\`\""

It needs a double backslash to escape the $ and backtick. It's showing as a single backslash here